# Doubly Linked List with forward and reverse iterators (javascript)

Tags: javascript, linked-list

A doubly linked list contains elements that include pointers to the previous and next element along with a value. Being able to search and iterate through the list in both directions is an important feature.

This is my improvement over the [previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277716/doubly-linked-list-javascript/277728#277728). I implemented it with classes, added a forward and reverse iterator, added a reverse search, and made reading at an index faster by starting at the end if the index is after the middle of the list.

I am looking for any advice on how this can be improved, both from a style and from a data structure perspective. If there are mistakes, or any redundant code, please tell me about it.

```
class ListElement {
  constructor(value, prev, next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class DoublyLinkedList {
  #size;
  #head;
  #tail;

  constructor() {
    this.#size = 0;
    this.#head = undefined;
    this.#tail = undefined;
  }

  #getListElement(index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.#size) return undefined;

    let currentElement;

    if (index < Math.floor(this.#size / 2)) {
      currentElement = this.#head;
      for (let step = 0; step < index; ++step) {
        currentElement = currentElement.next;
      }
    } else {
      currentElement = this.#tail;
      for (let step = this.#size - 1; step > index; --step) {
        currentElement = currentElement.prev;
      }
    }

    return currentElement;
  }

  #insertBefore(element, value) {
    const newListElement = new ListElement(value, element.prev, element);

    if (element.prev) element.prev.next = newListElement;
    else this.#head = newListElement;

    element.prev = newListElement;

    ++this.#size;
  }

  #insertAfter(element, value) {
    const newListElement = new ListElement(value, element, element.next);

    if (element.next) element.next.prev = newListElement;
    else this.#tail = newListElement;

    element.next = newListElement;

    ++this.#size;
  }

  size() {
    return this.#size;
  }

  empty() {
    let currentElement = this.#head;

    for (let step = 0; step < this.#size; ++step) {
      if (currentElement.prev) currentElement.prev.next = undefined;
      currentElement.value = currentElement.prev = undefined;
      currentElement = currentElement.next;
    }

    this.#head = this.#tail = undefined;
    this.#size = 0;
  }

  append(value) {
    if (this.#size === 0) {
      this.#head = this.#tail = new ListElement(value, undefined, undefined);
      this.#size = 1;
      return;
    }

    this.#insertAfter(this.#tail, value);
  }

  prepend(value) {
    if (this.#size === 0) return this.append(value);

    this.#insertBefore(this.#head, value);
  }

  headFind(value) {
    let currentElement = this.#head;

    for (let step = 0; step < this.#size; ++step) {
      if (currentElement.value === value) return step;
      currentElement = currentElement.next;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  tailFind(value) {
    let currentElement = this.#tail;

    for (let step = this.#size - 1; step >= 0; --step) {
      if (currentElement.value === value) return step;
      currentElement = currentElement.prev;
    }

    return -1;
  }

  read(index) {
    return this.#getListElement(index)?.value;
  }

  insert(index, value) {
    if (index < 0 || index > this.#size) return false;

    if (index === this.#size) {
      this.append(value);
      return true;
    }

    this.#insertBefore(this.#getListElement(index), value);

    return true;
  }

  remove(index) {
    const element = this.#getListElement(index);
    if (!element) return undefined;

    if (element.prev) element.prev.next = element.next;
    else {
      this.#head = element.next;
      this.#head.prev = undefined;
    }

    if (element.next) element.next.prev = element.prev;
    else {
      this.#tail = element.prev;
      this.#tail.next = undefined;
    }

    --this.#size;

    return element.v;
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let currentElement = this.#head;

    return {
      next: () => {
        if (currentElement) {
          const currentValue = currentElement.value;
          currentElement = currentElement.next;

          return { value: currentValue, done: false };
        } else {
          return { done: true };
        }
      },
    };
  }

  reverse() {
    return {
      [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
        let currentElement = this.#tail;

        return {
          next: () => {
            if (currentElement) {
              const currentValue = currentElement.value;
              currentElement = currentElement.prev;

              return { value: currentValue, done: false };
            } else {
              return { done: true };
            }
          },
        };
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Some test code to see it in action:

```
const list = new DoublyLinkedList();

list.append(20);
list.append(30);
list.append(40);
list.append(50);
list.insert(1, 5);
list.insert(3, 6);
list.insert(6, 7);
list.prepend(10);

for (let element of list) {
  console.log(element);
}

console.log();

list.remove(list.size() - 1);
list.remove(list.size() - 2);
list.remove(0);

for (let element of list) {
  console.log(element);
}

console.log();

console.log(list.tailFind(7));
console.log(list.headFind(5));
console.log(list.read(1));
console.log(list.read(list.size() - 2));
```

Comment: Can you post some code that exercises the list as you intend?

Comment: First observation is that `findHead` and `findTail` use equality comparison to determine match, which could be very limiting (for example comparing dates).  Providing a comparator callback might make it more flexible

Comment: @DaveMeehan I added a test example. But I don't intend much. This is just for learning and practice.

Comment: Have you considered a 'fluent' API (`list.append(1).append(2)` etc), and using exceptions rather true/false.  -1 for an not found is reasonable, but false for an insertion failure at a given index seems like it should be considered a logic error.  also, my previous comment regards using a comparator callback, or you're rather limited to scalar types as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice! A couple things:

Linked lists don't only optimize removing a single element, they are equally efficient at removing spans of elements by only detaching them at the ends. Thus, `empty()` can be greatly simplified to:

```js
empty() {
    this.#head = this.#tail = undefined;
    this.#size = 0;
}
```

*Though I wonder if your current implementation might be easier on the garbage collector...* Not worth thinking about.

Since you have iterators now, you can use them to minorly simplify your other code:

```js
headFind(value) {
    let step = 0;
    for (const e of this) {
        if (e === value) return step;
        ++step;
    }

    return -1;
}

tailFind(value) {
    let step = this.#size - 1;

    for (const e of this.reverse()) {
        if (e === value) return step;
        --step;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Writing iterators manually is a pain. That's one reason why the schmucks at JavaScript HQ gave us [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#generator_functions)! They let you write iterators like normal code; When `.next()` is called, the generator code will run until it reaches a `yield` statement, at which point `.next()` will return whatever you gave to the statement. But when `.next()` is called again, the generator code will continue right where it left off!

```js
// The asterisk * before the function makes it a generator function:
*[Symbol.iterator]() {
    for (let current = this.#head; current; current = current.next) {
        yield current.value; // Generator will pause until the next call to next()
    }
}

*reverse() {
    for (let current = this.#tail; current; current = current.prev) {
        yield current.value;
    }
}
```

Your iterators are relatively simple, but manual iterators get gross quickly if you need to do something advanced.

Besides that, here're a couple neutral notes:

- [My original suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/277728/221693) for remove() worked properly, but your version's redundant assignments to undefined might in fact make the code more readable. Wicked!
- I want to confirm that you understand the difference between `size()` and `get size()`. Ultimately, it's up to you if you want to use a method instead of a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for your API.
- Your test code at the end doesn't cover all your functions, nor does it test edge cases. This isn't really important since you're just mucking around, but this is a good place to practice unit tests. Things like "does `prepend()`/`append()` work when the list is empty?", "can I `insert()` into an empty list properly?" and so on.